# Three.js mesh position wont change

Tags: three.js

I have a mesh called mesh. I do this:

```
mesh.position.set(50,50,10);
console.log(mesh.position);
console.log("z: " + mesh.position.x);
```

Output:

```
THREE.Vector3
            x=0
            y=0
            z=0
            __proto__:Object
z: 10
```

How is this possible?

Comment: Do you have js errors?  Can you post a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

I yet again get to answer my own question. Yay.

The problem is with google chrome's console.log. If you log an object, it provides a twizzle to view properties of the object. So I can see the Vector3, then I twizzle to view x,y,z.

Trick is, the properties of Vector3 are only collected when you hit the twizzle. So I was seeing 0,0,0 a few updates in the future, after I hit the twizzle (that is a dumb word), whereas viewing the actual property displayed the value the instant I asked for it.

Be warned.

Comment: Could whoever voted this answer down please explain? Is this common sense that I never picked up on? Is it poorly worded?